# cancel intent doesn't call webhook in google-actions

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have created a google action project with dialog flow and action SDK, webhook and Android app to talk to it. Everything works fine except the "cancel" speech. I am asking user "Say cancel to cancel the order" but it closes the conversation itself.

Really need help here.

Comment: have you make a [tag:cancel] intent for canceling the order.

Answer (score 3):

When the user says "cancel", AoG's [App Exits](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/app-exits) functionality is triggered. This causes the app to immediately exit. We do this with certain key words (e.g. "exit", "cancel", "stop", "nevermind", "goodbye") so that users are never stuck inside an Action with no clear way to get out.

While you can handle an event that will allow you to return a custom response when an App Exit is triggered, there is no way to prevent this behavior.

To avoid this, you should guide the user towards using different language, or provide affordances such as [suggestion chips](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion-chip) that will allow them to easily take action.

The [Actions on Google design documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/design/be-cooperative#like_telling_a_joke_if_you_have_to_explain_it_youre_doing_it_wrong) recommends steering clear of "commands", avoiding statements such as `Say cancel to cancel the order`. Instead, you could ask the user if they'd like to cancel their order and handle `yes` or `no` as a response.